# SQL Count each time row equal to column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have the carriesOut table:

```
+------------+------------+
| theatreNo |   doctor   |  
+------------+------------+
|          1 | DD0094CYY  |  
|          1 | DD234CD1X  |  
|          2 | DD1199XYZ  |  
|          2 | DD1199XYZ  |  
|          4 | AB2323CYA  |  
|          4 | AB2323CYA  | 
+------------+------------+
```

And the doctor table:

```
+-------------+---------+
|  NINumber   |  lname  |
+-------------+---------+
| AB2323CYA   | Falk    |
| DD0094CYY   | Gibbson |
| DD1199XYZ   | Smith   |
| DD234CD1X   | Hammer  |
+-------------+---------+
```

I'm trying to find how many times every doctor has been in an operation, for example, I should get the output:

```
    +------------+---------+------------+
    |   doctor   |  lname  | operations |
    +------------+---------+------------+
    | DD0094CYY  | Gibbson |          1 |
    | AB2323CYA  | Falk    |          2 |
    | DD1199XYZ  | Smith   |          2 |
    | DD234CD1X  | Hammer  |          1 |
    +------------+---------+------------+
```

And here is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT o.doctor
     , d.lname
     , COUNT(theatreNo) operations
  FROM Hospital_CarriesOut o
  JOIN Hospital_Doctor d
    ON d.NINumber = o.doctor
 WHERE theatreNo IN (1,2,4)  
 GROUP 
    BY statement DESC
```

I only get the the following output:

```
+------------+---------+------------+
|   doctor   |  lname  | operations |
+------------+---------+------------+
| DD0094CYY  | Gibbson |          1 |
| AB2323CYA  | Falk    |          1 |
| AB2323CYA  | Falk    |          3 |
| DD234CD1X  | Hammer  |          1 |
+------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: It looks like your carriesOut table has duplicate rows. Does that table have a key?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions. In your query it'd be `GROUP BY Hospital_CarriesOut.doctor, Hospital_Doctor.lname`.

Comment: There's no 'statement' here

Comment: Also, your carriesout table has duplicated rows, which makes no sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be group by Hospital_CarriesOut.doctor, Hospital_Doctor.lname

```
   SELECT Hospital_CarriesOut.doctor, Hospital_Doctor.lname,
     COUNT(theatreNo) AS operations
    FROM Hospital_CarriesOut JOIN Hospital_Doctor ON Hospital_CarriesOut.doctor=Hospital_Doctor.NINumber WHERE theatreNo IN (1,2,4)  
    GROUP BY Hospital_CarriesOut.doctor, Hospital_Doctor.lname
```